# How to update data in Meteor using Reactivevar

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a page with a form. In this form user can add multiple rows with key and values. There is a restriction that the customFields is created on the fly, not from any subscribed collection.
...html

```
<template name="main">
{{#each customFields}}
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value="{{key}}"/>
                        <input type="text" style="width: 300px;" value="{{value}}"/>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
</template
```

.... router.js

```
Router.route 'products.add',
  path: '/products/add/:_id'
  data:
    customFields:[]
```

....products.js

```
#using customFieldSet as Reactive Var from meteor package
Template.product.created = ->
  @customFieldSet = new ReactiveVar([])


Template.product.rendered = ->
  self = this
  Tracker.autorun ->
    arr = self.customFieldSet.get()
    self.data.customFields = arr
Template.product.events(
'click .productForm__addField': (e)->
t = Template.instance()
    m = t.customFieldSet.get()
    console.log t
    m.push(
      key: ''
      value: ''
    )
    t.customFieldSet.set m
```

....

The last event will be trigger when I click the button. And it add another row with key and value empty to the page.

Please advise me why I actually see the reactive variable **customFieldSet** updated, but there is nothing changed dynamically in html.

P/s: I guess customFields is not updated via Iron router.

Comment: It's probably because assigning to `self.data.customFields` does not trigger the template re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you're doing the thing right. However, you shouldn't be assigning the new reactive data to your template's data context, but rather access it directly from your helpers:

```
Template.product.helpers({
  customFileds: function () {
    return Template.instance().customFiledsSet.get();
  },
});
```

Now you can use `{{customFields}}` in your template code and it should work reactively. Just remember that `{{this.customFileds}}` or `{{./customFileds}}` will not work in this case.